# FreeImage - read from base64-encoded char*

Tags: freeimage

I have a base64-encoded string (char[]) that represents a PNG image.

I want to create a FIBITMAP from that string - what's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/freeimage/Source%20Documentation/3.15.4/FreeImage3154.pdf) something like the following code should do the task:

```c
/* Needed here: data -> The string you want to read
                len  -> The length of the string */
char *decoded;
size_t decoded_len;
base64_decode(data, len, &decoded, &decoded_len); /* See note 1 below! */
FIMEMORY *mem = FreeImage_OpenMemory(decoded, decoded_len);
FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FreeImage_GetFileTypeFromMemory(mem, 0);
FIBITMAP *result = FreeImage_LoadFromMemory(fif, mem, 0);
/* [...] */
FreeImage_Unload(result);
FreeImage_CloseMemory(mem);
```

Note 1: FreeImage seems not to be capable of reading Base64-coded data directly. Thus, the data you want to use is decoded here. Please note that you have to provide an implementation for `base64_decode` (or modify the function call to match an existing implementation).

Comment: How can I now get the binary unsigned char* of the image (from result)?

Comment: @Gilad You can use `FreeImage_SaveToMemory` for that, as mentioned in the documentation.